# I have DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS format date to get inserted in oracle table, how can I define the DATE in CTL file?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-loader, sql-date-functions

SQL CTL : I have DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS format date to get inserted in oracle table, how can I define the DATE in CTL file?

Have defined date in ctl file as

```
C_DATE DATE "DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS"
```

I have no error in logs, but data inserted in table is in another format. Please guide which format should I give in CTL file to get the date inserted in correct format.

Answer (score 2):

A `DATE` field has not format itself. What you see is the data from default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting of your current session.

NB, when your date format is `DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS` why do you declare it as `DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS`?

Your year values might be `0020`, instead of `2020`